# How to wrap border design and box model together?

Tags: html, css

Expect design

[image]

My current design

[image]

I am looking for guidance on how to achieve a specific border design and box model that I have shown. Currently, my border design is within the box model. Can anyone provide advice on how to adjust my approach to achieve the desired design?

```css
.main {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main-cases {
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-cases-div {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.thick-border {
  border-color: #F7F7F7;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.smaller-image {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cases-div" style="background-color:#E2E2E2; height: 70px; width: 120px; margin-top: 7%; margin-left: 10%;">
  <img class="smaller-image thick-border" src="assets/images/data8logo.png" style="margin-left: 45px;">
  <p class="p" style="padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; color: #0E71B0;">Use<br> cases</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a question of box model. Box model is only the difference if the width/height includes the padding and border or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `position: relative` to the container. Then you can use `position: absolute` on the image to place the image at the top center of the parent element with `top: 0; left: 50%`. Last but not least you can offset the time by 50% outside of the parent and correctly place it in the horizontal center instead of left to it with `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

```css
.main-cases-div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.thick-border {
  border-color: #F7F7F7;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.smaller-image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cases-div" style="background-color:#E2E2E2; height: 70px; width: 120px; margin-top: 7%; margin-left: 10%;">
  <img class="smaller-image thick-border" src="assets/images/data8logo.png">
  <p class="p" style="padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; color: #0E71B0;">Use<br> cases</p>
</div>
```